# Where does this method come from

Tags: php

I'm currently working through a php how to book and a little puzzled by the following. Part of The code is;

```
$filesInFolder = new DirectoryIterator( $folder);
$file = $filesInFolder->current();
$filename = $file->getFilename();
```

I (think that I) understand that `$filesInFolder = new DirectoryIterator( $folder)` creates a new instance of `DirectoryIterator( $folder)` in `$filesInFolder` and that `$file = $filesInFolder->current()` is calling the method `current()` in to `$file`.

What I don't understand is where is the method `getFilename()` in `$file->getFilename()` coming from.

Is `$file = $filesInFolder->current()` creating a new instance of the class in `$file` or is something else happening?

Thanks

Comment: Look into the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.current.php#refsect1-directoryiterator.current-returnvalues You see that `current()` returns still an instance of DirectoryIterator, which has a method `getFilename()`

Comment: So is that calling another instance of itself inside $file?

Comment: Find it out yourself: `var_dump()` both variables and see if they refer to the same object. (The number after #X)

Comment: Ah, just found current() , that is php function, not unique to DirectoryIterator?

Comment: That is correct, that PHP also has a function called `current`, but with `->` you call the method which is also called `current` from the class `DirectoryIterator`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php Also if you go to http://php.net and type in current in the search field you see a lot of classes which have also a method called current

Comment: Still waiting for the lightbulb to go on...
In the manual it says that DirectoryIterator::current "Return the current DirectoryIterator item" I thought that this would be an array with info about the current file that it was pointing to?

Comment: At the end it is returning the object itself, e.g. `return $this;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106369/discussion-between-matt-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite valid. It is indeed confusing. What's more, the step of getting `->current()` can be omitted. This would also work:

```
$filesInFolder = new DirectoryIterator( $folder);
$filename = $filesInFolder->getFilename();
```

The [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class exposes a method [current](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.current.php):

> Return the current `DirectoryIterator` item.

This is in fact an implementation of the [`current` method](http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.current.php) of the [`Iterator` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).

The confusing thing here, is that the object returned by `DirectoryIterator::current` is again of the `DirectoryIterator` class. This class ***combines*** into one what you would expect to be segregated in separate classes:

- the [`SeekableIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.seekableiterator.php) methods (such as `next`, `rewind`, `seek`), which work on the *collection* of files, and
- the *current-item* methods (such as `getFilename`, `getSize`), which work on the *current* file.

So as these come together in one object, you don't need to call `current`, although some would still prefer that for consistency with how it works with other `Iterable` classes.

NB: Usually you would write code on an `Iterable` this way:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator( $folder) as $file) {
    $filename = $file->getFilename();
    // ... etc, maybe break;
}
```

This way you also deal with the case where there is no matching file at all.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense, Rizier123 explained pretty much the same in chat.

Answer (score 0):

1. Creates an instance of the DirectoryIterator

   ```
   $filesInFolder = new DirectoryIterator($folder);
   ```
2. Returns the DirectoryIterator object (not a new instance) assigned to `$filesInFolder`

   ```
   $file = $filesInFolder->current();
   ```
3. Returns the file name of the DirectoryIterator object assigned to `$file`.

   ```
   $filename = $file->getFilename();
   ```